# Async http request using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem not sending request when called from unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have the following static class, which has a send method which I use for fire and forget async http calls.

```
public static class AsyncHttpRequest
{
    public static void Send(string url)
    {
        //perform an async get on the url
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                o =>
                {
                    var response = request.GetResponse();
                    response.Close();
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Errors.ErrorSignal.SignalError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

A call to the same URL from a Web application project works great. But a call to the same URL from a unit test project does not work. It is not calling the URL. I checked in fiddler. Why is that?

In both cases i am calling like this -

```
AsyncHttpRequest.Send("http://example.com");
```

Comment: Have you tried to put breakpoint and see if you hit request.GetResponse() line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A call to the same URL from a Web application project works great. But a call to the same URL from a unit test project does not work. It is not calling the URL. I checked in fiddler. Why is that?

Because the unit test framework disposes everything quickly. You need to wait before exiting the unit test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    AsyncHttpRequest.Send("someUrl", x => evt.Set());

    Assert.True(evt.Wait(100));
}
```

And the class

```
public static class AsyncHttpRequest
{
    public static void Send(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                o =>
                {
                    var response = request.GetResponse();
                    response.Close();
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Errors.ErrorSignal.SignalError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void Send(string url, Action<HttpWebResponse> callback)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                o =>
                {
                    var response = request.GetResponse();
                    callback(response)
                    response.Close();

                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Errors.ErrorSignal.SignalError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right .. it was exiting and disposing everything before it would send the request.